# DNS CNAME not working properly on ios Iphone

Tags: ios, iphone, dns, cname

I'm working on an API for a mobile app and i'm using DNS CNAME in order to switch the mobile app from dev environment to production without rebuilding it. The problem is that the ios app will connect to the same subdomain even after the CNAME value has changed and the TTL was expired.
So i have a CNAME api.server.com that points to dev.server.com in the first instance to test the mobile app. When i change api.server.com to point to prod.server.com the mobile app still connects to dev.server.com even after TTL has expired.

Do you know what the reason for this might be?

Comment: Does the app itself really look the name up every time it connects?

Comment: I am not sure. It should once the DNS TTL expires. I'm not the actual mobile app dev. From what i see in the code, the URL of the API calls has the CNAME in it.

Comment: One thing to note: both dev.server.com and api.server.com are on the same IP. Could this cause an issue and make the ios use the old name when seeing the same IP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the problem. It was caused by improper vhost config on the server. Vhost didn't had alias for the CNAME and the web server was serving the first vhost set.